# " ch.setopt(ch.HTTPPOST, data.items()) TypeError: invalid arguments to setopt" i am getting this error

Tags: python, curl, pycurl, file-import

When I put all my authorization data into

```
data = {
  'token': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'content': 'file',
  'action': 'import',
  'record': '',
  'field': 'record_id',
  'event': '',
  'returnFormat': 'csv',
  'file': '(pycurl.FORM_FILE, file)'
}
```

I get error at

```
h.setopt(ch.HTTPPOST, data.items())
```

which says

> ch.setopt(ch.HTTPPOST, data.items())
>   TypeError: invalid arguments to setopt`

The rest of the code:

```
ch.setopt(ch.POST, 1)
ch.setopt(ch.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
ch.setopt(ch.HTTPPOST, data.items())
ch.setopt(ch.WRITEFUNCTION, e.write)
ch.perform()
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear. What do the API docs for what `h` is say? Since we don't know what `h` is there isn't much anyone else can do.

Comment: im sorry. Its ch.setopt(ch.HTTPPOST, data.items())

Comment: Details related to the question should be in the text of the question. You can [edit] your question and add details.

Comment: But what _type_ of thing is `ch`?